# Getting App Crashed alert even when the app is not launched

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I'm working on an application which uses external microphone using External accessory framework. We have a new build available in TestFlight. Downloaded the app from TestFlight but didn't launch it. Now, when I connect the external microphone, the app is crashing. The crash log clearly shows that the [UIApplication main] is called and the root view controller viewWillAppear call is being called and respective calls which is resulting in crash.
What could be the reason for these method calls without the app being launched.

Comment: Maybe showing the full crash log might help... Here we can't guess? Also, in XCode, Organizer/Crashes, where does it pinpoint the crash?

Comment: I could figure out the issue where it is crashing from the crash logs but my question here is, why's the [UIApplication main] getting called even when the app is not launched. Our app has External accessory communication enabled in "Background Modes". Could this be the issue? but we need this enabled for our app.

Comment: Hi @Larme, I checked with enabling and disabling the External Accessory communication in Background Modes. When I disable, the don't receive any notifications when the app is in suspended mode(Not running) but when enabled, I receive the notification even when the app is not in running state.